# How do I delete a specific row in a table in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

My last question was about deleting all rows in a table which is solved. The problem I am now having is how I would go abouts deleting a **specific** row which has a delete button on it. What I am trying to achieve is that when the button is clicked, that row which the button is on deleted.

The issue I am having now is that when I press the delete button on the row, it deletes the very first row on the table which is not what I want.

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState([]);
....
function singleDelete(i){
        var newArr = [...shop];
        newArr.splice(i, 1);
        setShop(newArr);
        setCount(count -1);
  }
```

Comment: its not clear whether the delete button exist on the first row. You shouldn't need to mantain a separate count state variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
setShop(shop.filter((_, index) => index !== i));
```

Also, don't maintain a separate `count` variable as it is redundant. The count can easily be retrieved with `shop.length`.

Comment: So I have changed the code to use `findIndex` and `splice` which works slightly better but still doesn't produce the results I want (it now deletes the row in front of it). The code is set here (
https://codepen.io/Guy-Fawkes-cc/pen/JjyPGgZ?editors=1010). I have also tried using the .filter method with my current code but nothing is happening (I must have implemented it wrong?) so I have just placed a snipped here (https://codepen.io/Guy-Fawkes-cc/pen/QWMLNwE?editors=0110) for you to see deeper what the issue is.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to be working. You can post it as a working snippet in a StackOverflow question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support I suggest you to post a new question because this one is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Using filter: `setShop(shop.filter((_, shopIndex) = shopIndex !== i));`

Answer (score 0):

Created working example here, you can use this sandbox
Link: https://codepen.io/naveenkumarpg/pen/GRvKpxM

for the reference you can take row id and delete the item.

```
remove = (rowId) => {
    // Array.prototype.filter returns new array
    // so we aren't mutating state here
    const arrayCopy = this.state.data.filter((row) => row.id !== rowId);
    this.setState({data: arrayCopy});
};
```